# create output for cacti using perl

Tags: perl, cacti

I have some trouble making the right script for cacti using perl.

This is the output of the data I can get:

```
Pac max phase 1: 2150W
Pac max phase 2: 0W 
Pac max phase 3: 0W
Energy Production:
        EToday: 7.282kWh
        ETotal: 1113.263kWh
        Operation Time: 2763.12h
        Feed-In Time  : 2376.42h
DC Spot Data:
        String 1 Pdc: 1917271.250kW - Udc: 280.00V - Idc:  2.118A
        String 2 Pdc: 1934451.875kW - Udc: 7789238.50V - Idc: 878461.750A
SUSyID: 246 - SN: 2002268779
AC Spot Data:
        Phase 1 Pac : 1635021.625kW - Uac: 237.10V - Iac: 1852400.000A
        Phase 2 Pac : 1730176.375kW - Uac:   0.00V - Iac: 1277195.375A
        Phase 3 Pac : 543451.500kW - Uac:   0.00V - Iac: 822742.312A
        Total Pac   :   0.560kW
```

I managed to get some data with a little script.

```
while(<STDIN>) {
chomp;
if (s/^Pac[ ]max[ ]phase[ ]1[]*[:][ ]*(\d+\.*\d+).*/\1/) {
print "Max:$_ ";
}
if (s/EToday[]*[:][ ]*(\d+\.*\d+).*/\1/) {
print "EToday:$_ ";
}
if (s/ETotal[]*[:][ ]*(\d+\.*\d+).*/\1/) {
print "ETotal:$_ ";
}
```

After EToday I get a lot off space in the return en I also want to get the value of Idc.
I have troubles to make the right output.
Can someone help me to create the following outputs:

```
Pac max phase 1: 
EToday: 
ETotal: 
Operation Time: 
Feed-In Time  : 
Udc:
Idc:
Uac:
Iac:
Total Pac   :
Grid Freq. :
```

aaa:xxxx b:xxxx c:xxxx etc.

Kind regards,
Martijn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show `Grid Freq.` in your dample data, but does this program solve your problem?

It forms a regex that matches any of the labels that you have listed, followed by a colon `:`  and a number, printing out all the occurrences of a pattern like that in each line of the input.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @fields = (
    'Pac max phase 1', 'Pac max phase 2', 'Pac max phase 3',
    'EToday', 'ETotal',
    'Operation Time', 'Feed-In Time',
    'Udc', 'Idc', 'Uac', 'Iac',
    'Total Pac',
    'Grid Freq.',
);

my $re = join '|', @fields;

my %printed;

while(<DATA>) {
  chomp;
  while ( /($re)\s*:\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)/g )  {
    print "$1: $2\n" unless $printed{$1}++;
  }
}

__DATA__
Pac max phase 1: 2150W
Pac max phase 2: 0W 
Pac max phase 3: 0W
Energy Production:
        EToday: 7.282kWh
        ETotal: 1113.263kWh
        Operation Time: 2763.12h
        Feed-In Time  : 2376.42h
DC Spot Data:
        String 1 Pdc: 1917271.250kW - Udc: 280.00V - Idc:  2.118A
        String 2 Pdc: 1934451.875kW - Udc: 7789238.50V - Idc: 878461.750A
SUSyID: 246 - SN: 2002268779
AC Spot Data:
        Phase 1 Pac : 1635021.625kW - Uac: 237.10V - Iac: 1852400.000A
        Phase 2 Pac : 1730176.375kW - Uac:   0.00V - Iac: 1277195.375A
        Phase 3 Pac : 543451.500kW - Uac:   0.00V - Iac: 822742.312A
        Total Pac   :   0.560kW
```

**output**

```
Pac max phase 1: 2150
Pac max phase 2: 0
Pac max phase 3: 0
EToday: 7.282
ETotal: 1113.263
Operation Time: 2763.12
Feed-In Time: 2376.42
Udc: 280.00
Idc: 2.118
Uac: 237.10
Iac: 1852400.000
Total Pac: 0.560
```

Comment: What I do to get the data is a bin/shell
/bin/sh SMAspot -v -nocsv | /var/www/cacti/scripts/solar.pl to get dat data.
The script works fine tnxs

Comment: But how do I identify Udc for string 1 and string 2?
Foor AC and DC. I only nead string 1 :)

Comment: @Martijn: You didn't mention that in your question. I've changed my answer to print only the first occurrence of every field

Comment: Just did a recompile of the program to remove the space and replace it with _